# .htaccess doesn't seem to work

Tags: .htaccess

I got a website with Zymic free hosting service and I added the following .htaccess to the main folder:

```
 <ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript  
</ifmodule>

 <IfModule mod_expires.c>  
# Enable expirations
ExpiresActive On

# Default directive
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

# My favicon
ExpiresByType image/x-icon “access plus 1 year”

# Images
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"

# CSS
ExpiresByType text/css “access 1 week”

# Javascript
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 3 month"

</IfModule>
```

This is for caching and compressing but when I check with google PageSpeed insights and other tools like it it's telling me there is no compressing or caching in my site.

What might be the problem?

Comment: Make sure .htaccess is enabled in httpd.conf. To test put some garbage text in .htaccess and see if you get 500 error in browser.

Comment: @anubhava How do I make sure? i didn't see any httpd.conf file in there.. do I need to create one myself like the .htaccess?

Comment: You can test it to verify (as I commented)

Comment: @anubhava I tested it and I get 500 error, now what?

Comment: Now tail your Apache access logs and make sure for image types defined above your are getting lines like this: `"GET /img/blank.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -` Status code 304 is for not modified.

Comment: @anubhava I don't think I can access those logs. Maybe I need to put "RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /" at the start? I saw some who did it..

Comment: Since you're not using mod_rewrite in your .htaccess therefore you will not need `RewriteEngine on RewriteBase /`. You should rather ask your hosting company how to access access.log for Apache.

Comment: the most obvious answer would be: both the modules are not enabled.